# A better way to do a rails query when selecting stocks from JOIN table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have 3 models, Portfolio, Stock and Transaction. When I'm in a portfolio show page I iterate through the portfolio's transactions and plot the stocks to show what I've bought.

When I load a portfolio show page the logs look something like this:

```
Started GET "/portfolios/1" for ::1 at 2016-09-24 02:15:32 -0400
Processing by PortfoliosController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Portfolio Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "portfolios".* FROM "portfolios" 
 WHERE "portfolios"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Transaction Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "transactions".* FROM "transactions"
 WHERE "transactions"."portfolio_id" = $1  [["portfolio_id", 1]]
  Stock Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "stocks".* FROM "stocks" WHERE "stocks"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Stock Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "stocks".* FROM "stocks" WHERE "stocks"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
  Stock Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "stocks".* FROM "stocks" WHERE "stocks"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "stocks".* FROM "stocks" WHERE "stocks"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
  Stock Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "stocks".* FROM "stocks" WHERE "stocks"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Stock Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "stocks".* FROM "stocks" WHERE "stocks"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 13]]
  Stock Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "stocks".* FROM "stocks" WHERE "stocks"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 9]]
  Stock Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "stocks".* FROM "stocks" WHERE "stocks"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 16]]
  Stock Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "stocks".* FROM "stocks"
  Rendered transactions/_form.html.erb (19.1ms)
  Rendered portfolios/show.html.erb within layouts/application (69.6ms)
  Rendered application/_nav.html.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 128ms (Views: 90.5ms | ActiveRecord: 9.2ms)
```

My transaction, stock and portfolio models have these associations:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :portfolio
  belongs_to :stock
end

class Stock < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transactions
end

class Portfolio < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :transactions
  has_many :stocks, through: :transactions
end
```

Within the show page, I loop through an instance portfolio and it's transactions using .each to grab the associated stock.

```
<% @portfolio.transactions.each do |trade| %>
```

In the portfolio controller the @portfolio is defined as @portfolio = Portfolio.find(params[:id]).

Is there a more efficient way to query the database (postgres) to retrieve the associated stock objects. Right now it's not a problem but I'm thinking of when people have a portfolio for a number of years and have hundreds of trades within the portfolio. Or should I be thinking of caching the results of a particular portfolio page using memcache or redis?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid these queries you need to preload associations.
Something like this

```
@portfolio = Portfolio.preload(:stocks).find(params[:id])
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an [**N + 1 queries problem**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations), you can use `eager_load` or `preload` or `includes` to get rid of it:

```
@portfolio = Portfolio.eager_load(:stocks).find(params[:id])
```

Answer (score 0):

I re-tooled my @portfolio object to @portfolio = Portfolio.includes(:transactions, :stocks).find(params[:id]).
Now I get all the stocks in one batch.

```
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Portfolio Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "portfolios".* FROM "portfolios"
WHERE "portfolios"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Transaction Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "transactions".* FROM "transactions"
WHERE "transactions"."portfolio_id" IN (1)
  Stock Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "stocks".* FROM "stocks" WHERE
"stocks"."id" IN (1, 6, 4, 2, 13, 9, 16)
  Stock Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "stocks".* FROM "stocks"
```

This is what I was trying to get. Since I'm using Rails 5 I'm not sure if eager_load or preload method are degraded. Includes seems like a more stable choice.